# Return non-matching nodes while creating relationships Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wrote a script to to batch create a bunch of relationship in neo4j. Here is the cypher:

```
:param batch => [{startId: 'abc123', endId: 'abc321'}, {startId: 'abc456', endId: 'abc654']
UNWIND $batch as row
MATCH (from {id: row.startId}
MATCH (to {id: row.endId}
CREATE (from)-[rel:HAS]->(to)
RETURN rel
```

The problem that there might be some startId/endId entries that don't match any nodes and are silently ignore. Is there a way to return the list of rows that don't match any nodes and create the relationship for the nodes that do match?

I tried OPTIONAL MATCH to fail-fast as soon an id doesn't find a startId/endId however, the query execution was really slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should always try to specify a *label* for the node that is used to kick off a `MATCH` (unless the `MATCH` pattern uses any already-bound nodes). Otherwise, every single node in the DB must be scanned. In addition, you should consider using [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) to speed up your `MATCH`s (but, again, you'd need to specify the labels).

Here is a query that uses the APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/#conditionals-overview) to create a new relationship when appropriate. It returns each `row` and the corresponding new relationship (or `NULL` if either node is not found):

```
UNWIND $batch as row
OPTIONAL MATCH (from:Foo {id: row.startId})
OPTIONAL MATCH (to:Foo {id: row.endId})
CALL apoc.do.when(
  from IS NOT NULL AND to IS NOT NULL,
  'CREATE (from)-[rel:HAS]->(to) RETURN rel',
  'RETURN NULL AS rel',
  {from: from, to: to}) YIELD value
RETURN row, value.rel AS rel
```

Comment: Thank you. I will apply all your suggestions.